# Laravel 5.7 cannot read css file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I need to use a custom css file but I am unable to call from the **public/css** directory.  Is there anything else I need to do?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/businessfrontpage.css')}}"/>
```

Comment: try to directly access `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/businessfrontpage.css"/>`
`

Comment: @SaurabhMistry  Tried but didn't work.

Comment: Resolved - it was a caching issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether it is loaded or not by opening the developer tools.
Second, while developer tools is open, right-click the refresh icon and click on the "Empty cache and hard reload" option.
Third, restart laravel server.

Answer (score 0):

That should work for the file `/public/css/businessfrontpage.css`.

Since it doesn't seem to be working for you, here are a few things you can try/check.

- Make sure `/public/css/businessfrontpage.css` actually exists at that specific path.
- Make sure the name is spelled **exactly** right.
- Try clearing your cache.

**If you are using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix):**

- Run `npm dev` *(or whichever build task you use)* and make sure Mix actually generates the right file and in the right path.
- If you are using versioning/cache busting via `mix.version()` make sure to use the `mix('path/to/file.css')` helper instead of `asset('path/to/file.css')`.

Answer (score 0):

give 777 permission to public folder and then try to access files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/businessfrontpage.css"/>
```